# animation of a straightline according to given constraints

Tags: manipulate, animation, constraint

I want to create an animation in which a linesegment of fixed length will move along a straight line(the line segment is attached to the straightline at its mid-point) [i should be able to vary the slope of the infinite st. line and also the line segment  and store the endpoints in a variable]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of `Graphics`, `Line`, `Manipulate` and such?

Comment: I am a beginner to mathematica, i could animate the line , but i just cant store the end points of the line-segment ...... I would need the end points to perform some inverse kinematics , could you please help ??

Comment: Please show us what you already tried and formulate your  question in clear way to facilitate helping you. Any relevant info should be edited into the question.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started. But need to make some effort yourself to finish it. It is just Manipulate, using Graphics and Line and little kinematics.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 tick;
 Module[{maxDistance = 100, maxTime = 10},
  currentDistance += speed*delT;
  x = currentDistance Cos[slope Degree];
  y = currentDistance Sin[slope Degree];
  currentTime += delT;
  If[currentDistance < maxDistance, tick = Not[tick]];

  Grid[{{currentTime},
    {
     Graphics[
      {
       {Thickness[.1], Red, 
        Line[{{x, y}, {x  + 0.1 maxDistance Cos[slope Degree], 
           y + 0.1 maxDistance  Sin[slope Degree]}}]},
       {Thin, Gray, 
        Line[{{0, 0}, {maxDistance Cos[slope Degree], 
           maxDistance Sin[slope Degree]}}]}
       }
      , PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1 maxDistance}, {- 1.1 maxDistance, 
         1.1 maxDistance}}, ImagePadding -> 5, ImageSize -> 200
      ]
     }
    }, Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> {1, 1}, Frame -> All]
  ]
 ,
 Grid[{
   {Button[
     "run", {currentTime = 0; currentDistance = 0; tick = Not[tick]}, 
     ImageSize -> {50, 40}], SpanFromLeft},
   {"slope (degree)", 
    Manipulator[
     Dynamic[slope, {slope = #; tick = Not[tick]} &], {-85, 85, 1}, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[slope]}
   ,
   {"speed (m/s)", Manipulator[Dynamic[speed, {speed = #;
        tick = Not[tick]} &], {0.1, 30, 0.1}, ImageSize -> Tiny], 
    Dynamic[speed]}
   }, Alignment -> Center],
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{slope, 45}, None},
 {{delT, 0.01}, None},
 {{speed, 10}, None},
 {{currentTime, 0}, None},
 {{currentDistance, 0}, None},
 Alignment -> Center,
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```